# Ohm's Law and in-series components

Tags: ohms-law, series

I am doing some practice problems based on what I learned today in lecture. However, I am stuck on this problem:

`A 10Ω resistor is in series with a bulb and a 12V source.`

`a. If 8V is across the bulb, what is across the resistor?
 b. What is the current in the circuit?
 c. What is the resistance of the bulb?`

Where would I begin solving what voltage is across the resistor? I do not the current, nor do I have the means to find it (that I can see), thus I can not find what voltage is dropped. I am not sure if I can assume the bulb has no resistance, in which case I can solve the problem easily.

Comment: A 12 volt source and 8V across the bulb and how much across the resistor? It has to add to 12 volts! Conservation of energy. Voltage - energy is conserved. Current - charge (matter) is conserved.

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer I thought that voltage could be dropped across a resistor, though? Or am I misunderstanding today's lecture? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Draw the circuit, and label the places for which you do know the voltages. Now simply read what the voltage across the resistor is...

Comment: Yes it drops and the bulb is also a resistance. To get 12V total, there MUST be 4V dropping across the resistor. Now you know the voltage and resistance (10 ohms) and you can calculate the current, and then the resistance of the bulb. You can also use a ratio method. 8/12 of the voltage drops across the bulb and 4/12 across the resistor. The bulb must have twice the resistance as the resistor. If I were grading a quiz I would be more impressed with the ratio answer as it shows a deeper understanding.

Comment: @Ryan_W4588 This will help you https://onlybooks.org/circuit-analysis-for-dummies-32278

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use KVL around the loop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsGw5X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

KVL says that the sum of the voltages around the loop equals 0. That means that if there is a 12V increase traveling from the negative to the positive terminal of the voltage source, then the voltage must fall by 12V traveling through the bulb and resistor.

The current in the loop can be found using Ohm's Law and from the voltage \$V\$ across the \$10\Omega\$ resistor you found in part (a).

The resistance of the bulb can then be found using Ohm's Law again: you are given the fact that 8V is across the bulb and from part (b) you know the current through it. Solve for the resistance \$R\$.

Comment: How do we know that 8V is across the 10Ω resistor? It is given that 8V is across the bulb, can we assume that 8V must also be across the resistor?

Comment: @Ryan_W4588 Sorry I read the problem wrong. I thought it said 8V was across the resistor. I fixed my answer.

Comment: So, can we assume that 8V is dropped at the resistor, because the voltage at the node following must have 0V (because there is nothing else to drop the voltage)? By assuming that, the answer to (a) would be zero (0). Thus, (b) is .8A.

Comment: @Ryan_W4588 No, the resistor does not have 8V across it. The bulb does. The resistor and bulb together have 12V across them (according to KVL). The difference between the 12V across both and the 8V across the bulb alone is the voltage across the resistor.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but I really appreciate the help! So, I think I was misunderstanding the meaning of "voltage drop" and confusing it with the current scenario. The resistor has 4V across it. Thus, we can conclude the answer to (b) is .4A and (c) is 20Ω, correct? Thanks again, I really appreciate the efforts!

Comment: @Ryan_W4588 You got it! And there was no inconvenience -- this is what we're here for.

Comment: Awesome! You're a life saver. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2):

Just remember that Voltage will divide/split across the resistors when they are connected in series(Note: Sum of voltage across all the resistors are equal to applied voltage(by KVL)) but the current remains constant in all the resistors. Similarly current divides across the resistors when they are connected in parallel(Algebric sum of current entering and leaving the node is equal to 0(by KCL)) but voltage remains constant across the resistors..

Solution for your problem,
[image]

Comment: The problem is first solved in the order V1,I,R2....Don't get confused.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the bulb as having reached equilibrium, this should do it:

[image]

Answer (score -4):

The voltage total has to equal 12 volts unles they are lying about it then you take the voltage youself butthis is theoretical so it is 12 volts. Subtract the voltage drop you know and it gives the voltage you dont know.
My math is not the greatest but a little kid could give you this counting on fingers 4 volts then your the college person that knows how to appie ohms law.
So you have resistance and voltage you find current you can get wattage. If the lightbulb is unenergized it has a differeent resistance than in an energized state. That has nothing to do with the anwer just screwing with you.
If the instructor gives you a circuit with a whole page of this with 21 elements its the same type of problem dont get nervous on the test just plug thru it finding each thing you can but dont make math mistake like 2 and 2 is five.

Comment: This answer could have used better proofreading before posting it and the side comments like "just screwing with you" are not appropriate for an answer.

Comment: This answer is not a good format for the site. There are spelling errors, missing spaces, lack of apostrophes, inappropriate commentary, and is difficult to understand in general.